# Jquery несколько modal dialog на странице

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Есть cshtml страница, на ней несколько div элементов, которые должны показываться как модальные окна, jquery код стандартного диалога:

```
           $("#add_edit-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            open:function(){{
                $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first")).css({ "z-index": "101" });
            }}
        });
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на любой submit, внизу страницы появляются и тут же исчезают все div, предназначенные для этих диалогов (правда в виде простого текста). Это мелькание довольно заметно, может быть кто-нибудь знает как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="add_edit-form" style="display:none;">...</div>
```

Они появляются не "при нажатии на любой submit", а при перезагрузке страницы - и тут же прячутся, когда выполняется код `$("#add_edit-form").dialog({...})`. Сделайте их изначально невидимыми, и они не появятся, пока Вы не вызовете

`$("...").dialog("open");`.

Comment: Работает! Спасибо!!! Небольшое дополнение к моему коду диалога,  если есть строчка: open:function(){{               $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first")).css({ "z-index": "101" });  , то некорректно потом отрабатывает диалог. Лучше эту строчку ($(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first")).css({ "z-index": "101" });) перенести за скобку } диалога.